# Creating your Context in extensions_custom.conf | Asterisk

Tags: asterisk

Salam! I'm trying to write my own context, but as a result, the curl request is not sent. I add files to extensions_custom.conf
Tell me, please, what's the matter?

```
[from-internal-custom]
include => from-internal
exten => recordcheck,n,Set(CHANNEL(hangup_handler_push)=send-filename,s,1)

[callblaster]
exten => 333,1,AGI(/var/www/html/callblaster/callblaster.php)

[send-filename]
exten => h,1,NoOp(Hangup context ${CONTEXT} completed)
exten => s,1,System(curl https://***.ngrok-free.app/test)
exten => s,n,Return()
```

I specify the context for SIP `from-internal-custom`

Comment: Please post your verbose logs

Comment: When do you think the curl call should be executed? What debugging have you done?

Answer (score 0):

s extension is EMPTY extension. In most cases you should use non-empty number pattern.

```
exten => recordcheck,n,Set
```

Line has no any sense. **n** mean next priority. You have no previous priority in this example, so it is incorrect. **recordcheck** extension in FreePBX can be found only inside **sub-record-check** context, which is for sure NOT in **from-internal-custom**.

For see what exactly happens on asterisk - use debug mode

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Collecting+Debug+Information

The main issue here is - you have to understand complex system if you are trying to hack it. Or you have start with plain asterisk and your own context, it will be simpler.

Instead of adding hangup handler to code you do not understand, I recommend you read cdr table in MySQL or use asterisk AMI/ARI events listener.